# How to generate a fax and send it in code

Tags: .net, fax, rightfax

I have a business requirement to generate a fax and send it to the recipient.  I know the recipients name and fax number and there is a PDF that will be attached.  This process will run daily and consist of 100 records to process each time.  I was under the impression that this could be done by sending an email to the fax machine and a quick test in Outlook worked just fine.  However, if I were to try and do the same thing in code, I get an error about the mail address being invalid.

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("[Fax:myUser@5555555555]"));
```

What are my options for sending faxes from code? (.NET)  These faxes are confidential in nature...

---

***EDITED INFO***

My company does use Right Fax.

Comment: You could always use SMTP directly...

Comment: @John - can you provide the sample/solution for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is some code that may help. This is using the Right Fax COM API Library (rfcomapi.dll)

```
RFCOMAPILib.FaxServerClass faxserver = new RFCOMAPILib.FaxServerClass();
faxserver.ServerName = "ServerName";
faxserver.Protocol = RFCOMAPILib.CommunicationProtocolType.cpNamedPipes;
faxserver.UseNTAuthentication = RFCOMAPILib.BoolType.True;
faxserver.OpenServer();

RFCOMAPILib.Fax fax = (RFCOMAPILib.Fax) faxserver.get_CreateObject(RFCOMAPILib.CreateObjectType.coFax);

// set up your 'fax' object the way you want it, below is just some sample options
fax.ToName = "John Doe";
fax.ToFaxNumber = "4255551111";
fax.ToVoiceNumber = "4255550000";
fax.ToCompany = "ACME";
fax.FromName = "My Company";
fax.FromVoiceNumber = "4255552222";

fax.Send();
```

Answer (score 2):

We use the RightFax dll.  That will only work if you have RightFax on your network though.

Comment: and where do you get RightFax.dll?

Comment: @JonErickson did you get 'rfcomapi.dll' I am also looking for this. please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Microsoft Fax Service, but you will need to set up a fax server..  A Google search should return some examples.

Add a reference to Interop.FAXCOMLib.dll

Here's an example (vb.net):

```
    Dim fs As FAXCOMLib.FaxServer
    Dim fd As FAXCOMLib.FaxDoc
    Dim result As Integer

    fs = New FAXCOMLib.FaxServer()
    fs.Connect("FaxServer1")

    fd = CType(fs.CreateDocument("c:\documenttofax.pdf"), FAXCOMLib.FaxDoc)
    fd.RecipientName = "John Doe"
    fd.FaxNumber = "555-1234"

    Try
       result = fd.Send()
    Finally
        fs.Disconnect()
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use eFax in which case you email a PDF (the faxed document) to eFax and they will fax it for you!  They are very cheap.

Comment: I'm not sure I would trust documents "confidential in nature" to a faxing service.