# RightFax and .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, fax, rightfax

How easy is it to integrate RightFax with .NET/C#?  We are considering FaxMan, Windows Fax Server also, but we came across RightFax.  We basically need to be able to send faxes through a .NET App, monitor status etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's some sample code for RightFax sending faxes, from [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988340/how-to-generate-a-fax-and-send-it-in-code/1013359#1013359), using the Right Fax COM API Library (rfcomapi.dll).

```
RFCOMAPILib.FaxServerClass faxserver = new RFCOMAPILib.FaxServerClass();
faxserver.ServerName = "ServerName";
faxserver.Protocol = RFCOMAPILib.CommunicationProtocolType.cpNamedPipes;
faxserver.UseNTAuthentication = RFCOMAPILib.BoolType.True;
faxserver.OpenServer();

RFCOMAPILib.Fax fax = (RFCOMAPILib.Fax) faxserver.get_CreateObject(RFCOMAPILib.CreateObjectType.coFax);

// set up your 'fax' object the way you want it, below is just some sample options
fax.ToName = "John Doe";
fax.ToFaxNumber = "4255551111";
fax.ToVoiceNumber = "4255550000";
fax.ToCompany = "ACME";
fax.FromName = "My Company";
fax.FromVoiceNumber = "4255552222";

fax.Send();
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm using the same code as yours but I get a "System.AccessViolationException" error on OpenServer() or when creating the fax object. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank!!

Answer (score 2):

there is a notification framework from [fuel9](http://www.fuel9.com/home) called Boomerang that supports windows fax server. The framework has a database interface so it supports .Net and anything else that may connect to a database server. I saw that they are working on a Rightfax extension as well but we have only MS fax in our infrastructure. Boomerang has been working great for us and with few sql statements will can create an automated fax (or email, printing, ftp etc) solution.

/B

Answer (score 1):

Consider also using the Fax Service in Windows.
[Using Windows Fax Service to Send Fax using C#](http://www.binaryspectrum.com/knowledge_bank/send_fax_using_CSharp.htm)

```
using FAXCOMLib;
using FAXCOMEXLib;

FaxServerClass fs = new FaxServerClass();
fs.Connect(“<your_computer_name>”); //specifies the machinename
object obj = fs.CreateDocument(“<your_filename>”);
FaxDoc fd = (FaxDoc)obj;
fd.FaxNumber = “<your_fax_number_to_send_to”;
fd.RecipientName = “<your_recipients_name”;
int i = fd.Send();
MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
fs.Disconnect();
```

Comment: To use Windows Fax Service, what would I need? Just a windows server 2003/2008 that's hooked up to a modem? Then I can just connect to the server with fs.Connect("servername") right?